Livewire: binding properties to route parameters instead of query parameters
I have a list / detail layout on a Livewire app on the route /emails/{emailId}.

When selecting an email on the list, I'd like to get URLs like /email/A, /email/B, etc. but keep the list scroll position as it is.
Three unsatisfying solutions to do that:

Using a classical href navigation, but the page will reload and I will lose the scrolling state of my list
Using wire:navigate and wire:scroll, but I still get a reset of the scroll position as the component is re-rendered
Using a $id property to load the details + #[Url], but the url will look like /emails?id=A and not /emails/A

Is there a livewire way to update the route parameters when updating properties ?

So, you want to work this as pagination, right?

@MiteshRathod More like a details page of a email inbox. Added a more explicit example on the initial question

Thanks for the update question, it will give clear idea!..

You can set 2 separate components, 1 for listing, and 2nd for details, and in listing and details page you need to set flag. when you click on the item from list, using event listener change the flag status from detail component.

How does splitting the component helps with URL ? I'm not sure to understand your solution


In ListEmailComponent, You need to list the emails.
In ShowEmailComponent, you need to display the content.


On click, you need to you dispatch event to change the flag to ShowEmailComponent display content and also pass the slug/id here.

Using the #Url Attribute you can change the URL

I already have that (that's solution 3), but my URL looks like /emails?id=A and not  /emails/A. The core issue here is that #Url works with additional query params, but not as path parameters
